# How to change value of variable by UISwitch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, uiswitch

I am a beginner to Xcode and Swift and I am currently creating an application where the user adds a person on the application and after that it right the amount of money they owe that person or that person owes him/her.

Note: I have used core data to store all the value

I actually want to change the value of a variable when switch is on and off. For instance, in the following I want the "amount" to be negative when the switch is on and positive when it is off. Also, when I try to do this and send amount variable to previous view controller I can't send the value depending on the UISwitch because it always shows positive. I am trying to find a solution to this from past 3 days therefore can you please help me? Thanks a lot in advance

Owe ViewController

```
import UIKit

class NewOweTableViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var locationTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!
        AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var owe: Owe?
    var dataInfo: [Owe] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden = true
        let saveBTN = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.save, target:self,
                                      action: #selector(saveButtonTapped(_:)))
        let deleteBTN = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItem.trash, target:self,
                                        action: #selector(deleteButtonTapped(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [saveBTN, deleteBTN]

        if !dataInfo.isEmpty {
            titleTextField.text = dataInfo[0].name
            amountTextField.text = (NSString(format: "%.2f", (dataInfo[0].amount) as CVarArg) as String)
            locationTextField.text = dataInfo[0].location
            datePicker.date = dataInfo[0].date!
        }
    }

    @objc func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
        if !dataInfo.isEmpty{
            let data = dataInfo[0]
            data.name = titleTextField.text
            data.amount = Double(amountTextField.text!)!
            data.location = locationTextField.text
            data.date = datePicker.date
        }
        else if titleTextField.text == "" || amountTextField.text == "" || locationTextField.text == "" {
            return
        }
        else{
            let data = Owe(context: context)
            data.name = titleTextField.text
            data.amount = Double(amountTextField.text!)!
            data.location = locationTextField.text
            data.date = datePicker.date
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }

    @objc func deleteButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton){
        if !dataInfo.isEmpty{
            let data = dataInfo[0]
            context.delete(data)

            do {
                try context.save()
                navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func oweSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        if sender.isOn {
            owe?.amount = (owe?.amount)! * (-1)
            amountTextField.textColor = UIColor.green
        } else {
            owe?.amount = (owe?.amount)! * (1)
            amountTextField.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Previous View Controller

```
import UIKit

class PersonDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext


    var totalLabel: UILabel?
    var person: People?
    var owe: Owe?

    @IBOutlet var personTable: UITableView!

    var dataInfo: [Owe] = []
    var selectedObject: [Owe] = []
    var balanceAmount = "Balance: "

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (dataInfo.count)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = personTable
            .dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "detailsCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = dataInfo[indexPath.row].name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "₹ \(dataInfo[indexPath.row].amount)"
        if dataInfo[indexPath.row].amount < 0 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        } else {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.green
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedObject = [dataInfo[indexPath.row]]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "addOweDetails", sender: nil)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getData()
        personTable.dataSource = self
        addTotalToNav()
        print(dataInfo as Any)
    }



    // MARK: - Table view data source

    func addTotalToNav() -> Void {
        if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
            let totalFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width/2, height: navigationBar.frame.height)

            totalLabel = UILabel(frame: totalFrame)
            totalLabel?.text = balanceAmount
            totalLabel?.tag = 1
            totalLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
            totalLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
//            navigationBar.large = totalLabel?.text
            self.title = totalLabel?.text

        }
    }


    func getData() -> Void {
        do{
            dataInfo = try context.fetch(Owe.fetchRequest())
            var total:Double = 0.00
            for i in 0 ..< dataInfo.count {
                total += dataInfo[i].amount as! Double
            }
            balanceAmount = "Balance: ₹" + (NSString(format: "%.2f", total as CVarArg) as String)
        }
        catch{
            print("Fetching Failed")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc = segue.destination as! NewOweTableViewController
        vc.dataInfo = selectedObject
        selectedObject.removeAll()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getData()
        personTable.reloadData()
        if (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.viewWithTag(1)?.isHidden == true){
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
            addTotalToNav()
        }
    }

}
```

Core Data for owe

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(Owe)
public class Owe: NSManagedObject {
    var date: Date? {

        get{
            return rawDate as Date?
        }
        set {
            rawDate = newValue as NSDate?
        }
    }

    convenience init?(name: String?, location: String?, amount: Double, date: Date?) {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
            else {
                return nil
            }

        self.init(entity: Owe.entity(), insertInto: context)

        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.amount = amount
        self.date = date

        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you send data from oweVC to previousVC ??

Comment: The `amount` logic is flawed. You need something like `owe?.amount = abs(owe.amount ?? 0) * (sender.isOn ? 1 : - 1)`

Comment: More importantly, the `owe` variable is never initialised: it is always nil.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there and welcome to the Swift Community!

If I understand correctly, you are trying to propagates updates backwards from `NewOweTableViewController` to `PersonDetailTableViewController`. If that is the case, an easy way to achieve this with your MVC architecture is by passing a closure to `NewOweTableViewController` when you initialize it in `PersonDetailTableViewController`.

In order to do so,

1. Update `NewOweTableViewController` and add a closure property.

   ```
   class NewOweTableViewController: UIViewController {

       // ...

       var switchValueUpdate: ((Bool) -> ())?

       // ...
   }
   ```
2. Make sure you call this closure inside your `@IBAction` that you link to your switch in `NewOweTableViewController`

   ```
   @IBAction func oweSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
       if sender.isOn {
           owe?.amount = (owe?.amount)! * (-1)
           amountTextField.textColor = UIColor.green
       } else {
           owe?.amount = (owe?.amount)! * (1)
           amountTextField.textColor = UIColor.red
       }
       switchValueUpdate?(sender.isOn)
   }
   ```
3. update `PersonDetailTableViewController` to set the closure

   ```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

       let vc = segue.destination as! NewOweTableViewController
       vc.dataInfo = selectedObject
       selectedObject.removeAll()

       vc.switchValueUpdate = { (isOn) in
           // Here you go, update PersonDetailTableViewController to reflect changes related to the switch!
       }
   }
   ```

That's it! Let me know if you have any question on that code, hope it helps!

Comment: In vc.switchUpdate I tried to save the state of the UISwitch but cannot get it right. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You don’t need to save the state, you have it inside the closure. If you want to save it inside PersonDetailsTableVC you can create a stored variable and update it inside the closure that you create in point 3)

Comment: Can you please do it in the edit? As I am not understanding